# I'm about to sell my Mac. What should I delete?

Tags: macos, mac

I'm looking to sell my Mac and because I am unable to format and make a fresh reinstall, I'd like to just delete sensitive files.

What files or folders should I delete to be as safe as possible from leaving personal data on the disc?

Comment: Duplicate of http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/106005/i-didnt-wipe-my-hard-drive-before-i-sold-it-how-would-a-criminal-take-advantag

Comment: Similar but not the same. In that question the user is able to format the hard drive.

Comment: Erased data is possible to recover from any hard disk. Use *diskutil secureErase* to properly format your hard drive. It will take a few hours, be patient.

Comment: @CJDana is that true even for an SSD hard drive?

Comment: Nope, *Flash Based Storage(SSD)* erases a file down to its trace routes. Hard drives are much different, the disks do not have a way of removing data like a SSD, they technically only rewrite data to appear as *free space.*

Comment: Why can't you format your hard drive?

Comment: Also see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/147478/im-planning-to-sell-my-laptop-and-i-need-to-know-if-i-have-my-bases-covered-k?rq=1

Comment: @patrix the accepted answer for that question was "get the install CD and reformat". I do not wish to format and reinstall.

Comment: @patrix I don't want to format and reinstall because it's a Hackintosh, meaning I'd have to download drivers and reconfigure everything. It takes time and I'm not ready to research how it's done.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question says Mac and the correct solution is reformat - but the OP rejects this as he says it is a Hackintosh and that is not in the question

Comment: Have a look at: [What to do before selling or giving away your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201065)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything. Delete all of your applications. Create a new user account with a generic name and password (like "guest"/"guest") and make that account an administrator. Log in with that account and then delete the home folder of your account. These two steps are the best way to get rid of the data. That being said, it is possible to recover this data if the person you are selling it to has malicious intent. Be careful with your data! Best way to be safe is to sell the computer without the hard drive (but that doesn't seem to be an option for what you want to do).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you should delete all your info. As stated on https://macback.co.uk You should delete all of your personal information off of your device before you sell it. You also need de-authorise iTunes and any other apps that you have given permission to. You’ll want to sign out of iTunes, iCloud, and iMessage as well.